# How to not delete last item from my array

Tags: arrays, angular

I have a problem with deleting an item from an array. My current piece of code is removing the item. But it it always the last one not the one that I choose. I have found some clues that index needs to be checked against -1

Array

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.todos = [
        {
            text: 'Pick up'
        },
        {
            text: 'Meeting'
        },
        {
            text: 'Dish washing'
        }
    ];
}
```

Functions

```
addTodo(){
    this.todos.push({
        text: this.text
    });
}
deleteTodo(todoText){
    this.todos.splice(this.todos.indexOf(todoText), 1);
}
```

Comment: make sure you pass the todo item itself and not the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not pass only the `todoText` to your deletion method, pass the whole `todo`, so if your template looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let todo of todos" (click)="deleteTodo(todo)">
  {{todo.text}}
</div>
```

and then your delete method works fine in your TS:

```
deleteTodo(todo){
  this.todos.splice(this.todos.indexOf(todo), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem in your code is that you are compare by object reference, so do this :

```
 deleteTodo(todoText){
    this.todos
        .splice(this.todos.map(todo=>todo.text)
        .indexOf(todoText.text), 1);
  }
```

I'm assuming that todoText argument is an object that has text property.

if you want to delete by text:

```
deleteTodo(text){
        this.todos
            .splice(this.todos.map(todo=>todo.text)
            .indexOf(text), 1);
}
```